# Wordpress dynamic thumbnail size adjustment

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, wordpress

I manage many wordpress websites and some of them have a responsive CSS design.
The problem with responsive CSS is that images are scaled to fit changing screen sizes, which is not really good in terms of page optimization.

Yslow tells me "do not scale images in HTML" and it's right : Why load a 960x720px image on a screen where page width is 320px, 480px or 576px.

If I can afford some dynamic thumbnail loading (thumbnails are already generated) then it should load the fittest thumbnail to screen size.

Is there any plugin or script providing such functionality ?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

The `srcset` attribute has decent [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset), especially with browsers that users are likely to running on mobile devices (Safari, Chrome, Android browser). If you need support beyond that, there are polyfills but I don't know how well they are going to work, since you're fighting against the browser doing something it desperately wants to do - preload all page elements as quickly as possible.

If you're looking for a Wordpress plugin to handle things for you, there's this: https://github.com/ResponsiveImagesCG/wp-tevko-responsive-images It does seem like you'll need to regenerate your thumbnails rather than creating them dynamically.